How to adopt Transformers for classifying time series of 2D images irregularly sampled across multiple filters?
I’m working on classifying time series of 2D images observed in multiple filters (or channels), but not at the same time. For example, I have observations in two filters—g-band and r-band—taken at different timestamps, see below. (Since we’re working with astronomical data, the observation epochs aren’t under our control.)

In this setup, I want to make predictions whenever a new image arrives, meaning four times for the example above, while considering all prior data. A brute-force approach might involve using ConvLSTM2D and padding the missing band images, but this isn’t ideal since the model has to learn from padded data.
I believe Transformers could be more effective here, as they are designed to handle temporal correlations and have since been adapted for spatial correlations as well (ViT). Could you provide guidance on adapting Transformers to handle multi-channel data with both spatial and temporal correlations?
Thanks in advance.
